# La etiqueta <a> arruina toda la composición

Tags: php, css

estoy intentando que quede todo seguido pero queda como la imagen el problema es una etiqueta  que no encuentro en el código pero en el buscador si aparece uso semantic funciona poniendo  pero no queda para darle clic tambien intente meter todo en una sola etiqueta y no pude (#relleno |soy algo nuevo en stackoverflow y no me deja publicarlo cuantos caracteres son?)

[image: imagen del error]

```
 <div class="background_main">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <h1 class="main_title">Safe Content</h1>
    </div>
    
        <div class="sixteen wide column" style="margin-top: 20px;"> 
           <h2 style="text-align: center;">Publicaciones Recientes</h2>
        </div>
    
    <div class="ui grid stackable container" style="margin-top: 15px;">
        
        <a href="#" class="four wide column">
           <div class="post_container">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1280x720" class="post_img" alt="Imagen prueba">
                <h2 class="post_title">Name</h2>
                <p class="post_date">02/12/2020</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="four wide column">
           <div class="post_container">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1280x720" class="post_img" alt="Imagen prueba">
                <h2 class="post_title">Name</h2>
                <p class="post_date">02/12/2020</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="four wide column">
           <div class="post_container">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1280x720" class="post_img" alt="Imagen prueba">
                <h2 class="post_title">Name</h2>
                <p class="post_date">02/12/2020</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="four wide column">
           <div class="post_container">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1280x720" class="post_img" alt="Imagen prueba">
                <h2 class="post_title">Name</h2>
                <p class="post_date">02/12/2020</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="four wide column">
           <div class="post_container">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1280x720" class="post_img" alt="Imagen prueba">
                <h2 class="post_title">Name</h2>
                <p class="post_date">02/12/2020</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="four wide column">
           <div class="post_container">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1280x720" class="post_img" alt="Imagen prueba">
                <h2 class="post_title">Name</h2>
                <p class="post_date">02/12/2020</p>
            </div>
        </a>
              
    </div>
```

Comment: en la imagen aparece una etiqueta <a> que no se de donde sale por que esta vacia y me mueve todo

Comment: Tu error no está en el html, al menos en el que colocas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solución fue agregar un  donde se ponia div class="ui grid stackable container" style="margin-top: 20px; y listo solucionado.

```
<div class="background_main">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <h1 class="main_title">Safe Content</h1>
</div>

<div class="ui grid stackable container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    </a>
    <div class="sixteen wide column"> 
       <h2 style="text-align: center;">Publicaciones Recientes</h2>
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="four wide column">
       <div class="post_container">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1280x720" class="post_img" alt="Imagen prueba">
            <h2 class="post_title">Name</h2>
            <p class="post_date">02/12/2020</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```